# .map is not a function in React production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

When running my express react app build locally the map function works flawlessly, however whenever I switch to production. I get the error that map is not a function.

Error comes up pointing towards 'let returnlist' line. I have included the index.js and where the error occurs.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import AddNewPerson from './component/addNew'
import Filter from './component/filter'
import Persons from './component/persons'
import axios from 'axios'



const App = () => {
  const [persons, setPersons] = useState([])
  const [tempPersonList, setTempPersonList] = useState([])
  const [ newName, setNewName ] = useState('')
  const [ newNumber, setNewNumber] = useState('')

  let searchInput = false;
 
useEffect(() => {
 
  axios
    .get('http://localhost:3001/init')
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response.data)
      setPersons(response.data)
      setTempPersonList(response.data)
    })
}, [])

  return (
    <div>

      <Filter persons = {persons} setPersons= {setPersons} tempPersonList = {tempPersonList} 
      searchInput = {searchInput}/>
      <AddNewPerson persons = {persons} setPersons= {setPersons} newName = {newName}
      setNewName = {setNewName} setNewNumber = {setNewNumber} newNumber = {newNumber} />
      <Persons persons = {persons} setPersons = {setPersons} tempPersonList = {tempPersonList} searchInput = {searchInput} />
     
 
    


    
      ...
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

The error occurs in the code below on 'let returnList'.

```js
const Persons = (props) => {

    const persons = props.persons
    const setPersons = props.setPersons
    const tempPersonList = props.tempPersonList
    let searchInput = props.searchInput


  

    let returnList = persons.map((person) => <li className='contact' key = {person.number}>{person.name} : {person.number}  <button onClick={
        () =>{  Axios.delete(`${url}/${person.id}`)
        .then((response) =>{
         
            setPersons(persons.filter(personCheck => personCheck.id !== person.id ))


        })}}>Remove</button></li>)

  let returnSearchList = tempPersonList.map((person) => <li key = {person.number}>{person.name} : {person.number}  <button onClick={
    () =>{  Axios.delete(`${url}/${person.id}`)
    .then((response) =>{
     
        setPersons(persons.filter(personCheck => personCheck.id !== person.id ))


    })}}>Remove</button></li>)



  

    return(
    <div>
        <h2>
            Numbers
        </h2>
    {searchInput ? returnSearchList   : returnList} 

    </div>
    )
}


export default Persons
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your response data doesn't return an array, it's probably an object. Check in the network tab of your browser what your AJAX call returns.

Or just open this in your browser: http://localhost:3001/init

The `data` field of whatever is shown has to be an array.

Comment: Thank you I did not think of that! However for some reason, I thought I'd debug it how you mentioned and for some reason it started working again in production. After my PC had restarted.

Comment: @firedust is it possible that your server wasn't running and as such your AJAX call didn't actually work? I suppose in that case your `response.data` would be undefined and that would also mean no `.map()`

You should probably add a `.catch()` to your axios call to catch any sort of errors thrown because of connectivity issues.